# MySql: Select from table based on rank increase

Tags: mysql

For example I have the following data:

```
rank         value
___________________
1            "A"
2            "B"
5            "C"
3            "D"
4            "E"
6            "F"
```

I only want to select the values when the rank is increased, so I should only be getting

```
"A", "B", "C", "F".
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by increase? Could you give examples? Sou

Comment: increased compared to what? Do you have any column that defines an order on the table?

Comment: OP obviously thinks of his data as ordered (we can imagine a hidden `order` column which goes from 1 to 6). No immediate idea on how to do it in pure sql, though.

Comment: Let's assume it was ordered by a hidden id column. I only want to select the rows when the value of row "rank" is larger than previous max value, so only the rows with value of rank 1, 2, 5 and 6 will be picked as rows with rank 3 and 4 are less than the previous largest value of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is numeric id column, then you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
    value
FROM
    tbl AS t1       
WHERE
    (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(rank), 0) FROM tbl AS t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id) < t1.rank
```

The IFNULL is there because of the first row.